# Zen coding downloading trouble

Tags: emmet, sublimetext

Hello to all you people out there

I have been trying to download the zen coding plugin for sublime text 2, but as it seems right now, the only place you can download it is at bitbucket.

The problem is, that bitbucket wont allow me to download it, even though i have signed up and everything...

So if some nice guy could show me another download link or send me the file(code?), I would really appreciate it.

Thanks

Comment: I am also having the same issue. I want to purchase the product, but ZEN Coding is a must and I cannot find it for SublimeText 2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

for some reason the zen coding package has been removed from the Sublime Text 2 package control.

I believe it will back.

meanwhile, I reZipped the Zen coding from Sublime folder, and you can install it by putting it in \Sublime Text folder\Data\Packages

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/1292831/ZenCoding.zip

Comment: FIX: 
#1] Add the folder to C:\Documents and Settings\XXXUSERXXX\Application Data\Sublime Text 2\Packages\
#2] In the newly added folder \ZenCoding - delete the file "zen-coding.sublime-settings..."
#3] Restart [or logoff-loggon] and run Sublime Text 2

It is now working -- thanks so much!