# How do I activate the Zen coding key bindings in Sublime Text 2?

Tags: sublimetext, emmet

I just downloaded the Zen coding package for Sublime Text 2, but I can't figure out how to activate it.

I already have it in Netbeans, and here you just have to press <kbd>CTR</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd>, but this doesn't work in the Sublime editor.

Google didn't yield any results, so I'm asking here.

Can someone tell me how to activate the Zen coding function?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> and you'll get a text input box at the bottom of the screen, titled: `Enter Koan:`. as you type the zen expression into the box it will simultaneously unfold on the screen.

Alternatively, you can type the zen expression in the editor and press <kbd>tab</kbd> to expand it. Be sure not to leave any spaces inside the expression or after it.

Answer (score 12):

I have been using Sublime Text 2 beta, build 2139 on Windows (but I'm also pretty sure this should work on Mac OS and Linux too) and here's how I got it to work:

1. After installing Sublime Text 2 itself, install [Package Control](http://wbond.net/sublime_packages/package_control/installation)
   for Sublime Text 2. This is an add-on that allows you to easily
   manage another add-ons.

   I couldn't get the first installation option to work so I went for
   the manual method. On my installation there was no folder called
   "Installed packages", instead I've used "Pristine Packages" folder
   which seemed to contain other, already installed extensions.

   Restart Sublime Text 2
2. With Package Control installed open Sublime Text 2 editor and choose Preferences ->               Package Control -> Package Control : Install Package from the menu. Hit "Enter" and there should be a list of packages available for installation displayed on the screen. Start typing "Zen" and Zen-Coding will be presented. When selected hit "Enter" again, status bar on the bottom of the screen will be showing installation progress.
3. When it's done - restart Sublime Text 2 one last time. Now, you can expand Zen-Coding abbreviations with 'ctrl+space' or 'tab'.

Remember it will only work in the saved file, with extension "html". (in particular - it won't work on the new document you've just created).

I hope this helps

Comment: The key information here for me was "it will only work in the saved file, with extension .html". I hadn't saved my file and didn't know why it wasn't working.

Comment: you dont have to save the file for it to be html, it can be html by click at right bottom corner and choosing html.

Answer (score 2):

To expand your zencoding, just press <kbd>TAB</kbd>.  However, for a full list of all the keybindings, look in your Zencoding folder for a file called "Default (NAME_OF_YOUR_OPERATING_SYSTEM).sublime-keymaps".  To get to the package, go to "Preferences > Browse Packages > zencoding".

Answer (score 2):

Ctrl + Opt (Alt on a PC) + Enter. Check out [the video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q_D7X1Y8uOA).

Answer (score 0):

See this post : [Zen coding downloading trouble](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8099358/zen-coding-downloading-trouble)
and my comments for detailed instructions.

Also, after an upgrade, just replace the folder with the original one from
http://dl.dropbox.com/u/1292831/ZenCoding.zip

Good Luck ..

Answer (score 0):

Download this one; https://github.com/sergeche/zencoding-sublime 
It works on SublimeText2 2.0.1 build 2217 windows.

Comment: How does this answer the question?

Answer (score 0):

After install Emmet package, remember to restart sublime editor and save a file first to try it!. I thought it wasn't working after install, but it just needs a saved file to work on it.